# How to send A get Request by php with parameters if the hosting don't have the CURL extension?

Tags: php, javascript

I need to send a sms when the user submit the form, i have 2 ways send it by javascript

```
$.ajax({
        url: encodeURI('http://gate.smsaero.ru/send/?user=myuser&password=mypassword&to=4920942894&text=test&from=fromTest'),
        type: 'GET',
        crossDomain: true,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        success: function() { alert("Success"); },
        error: function() { alert('Failed!');
 }
```

but here i have a problem that i get an error about the login and password is incorrect, is here a encoding problem or something may be?

or send it by php with parameters but the hosting does not provide CURL library, how can i send it?

Comment: Try your url manually in a browser's address bar. If the login error is still there then check your username/password again with the service provider. If not then you can also try the php way as suggested by Gareth below

Comment: Hey, great. You are giving away your credentials and let everyone send SMS with free choice of target numbers and free choice of text. And you'll pay the bill! Instead I'd rather suggest you use the PHP method!

Comment: i've tried to do it in the browser, but it still say that login or password is incorrect, but when i login in the service its all okay....

Comment: yes what about if all will see the credentials i know, but i don't care , i need to make it work :)

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Answer (score 0):

In PHP, you could try:

```
$result = file_get_contents('http://gate.smsaero.ru/send/?user=myuser&password=mypassword&to=4920942894&text=test&from=fromTest');
```

Comment: Warning: file_get_contents(): http:// wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0

Comment: It sounds like your PHP administrator had deliberately closed any access to the outside world - you'll probably have to rely on javascript.